# Strange String Format (from selenium scrape) Only Appears After Join and Split

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, format

so I have a df that I got from a scrape of BOM, it's a bit of a lazy scrape where I just added everything from the web element to a new row.

Anyway, when I join the rows and parse into sentences I get this weird formatted string style I also lose a bracket that I'll point out below.

The df is as follows:

```
        main_data
 0  Transformers: The Last Knight
 1  Grosses
 2  DOMESTIC (21.5%)
 3  $130,168,683
 4  INTERNATIONAL (78.5%)
 5  $475,256,474
 6  WORLDWIDE
 7  $605,425,157Distributor
 8  Paramount Pictures
 9  See full company information
10  Opening
11  $44,680,073
12  4,069 theaters
```

I added an strix to the last row and then used this code to join and parse and create the new df is as follows:

```
 #Join/Split and Dataframe Creation
 bom_join = ' '.join([x for x in df1['main_data]])
 bom_join = bom_join.split('*')
 bom_df = pd.DataFrame({'main_data': bom_join})
```

Then the strings look like this...

```
    main_data   
0   Transformers: The Last Knight Grosses DOMESTIC (21.5%)  
    130,168,683(78.5 475,256,474 WORLDWIDE 
    605,425,157 44,680,073 4,069 theaters 
    Budget $217,000,000 Release Date Jun 21, 2017 - Aug 24, 2017 MPAA PG-13 Running Time 2 
    hr 34 min Genres Action Adventure Sci-Fi In Release 194 days/27 weeks Widest Release 
    4,132 theaters IMDbPro See more details at IMDbPro  Transformers: The Last Knight    
    Paramount Pictures  10.34%
```

Its only temporary and cosmetic its gone when I look at a pandas series....and Im okay with the noise in the row I can parse the stuff I need

but can anybody explain why it's not formatted in the first dataframe turns formatted in the new dataframe.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It originates from the $ symbols When I remove the $ signs the formatting returns to normal

```
bom_df['main_data'] = bom_df['main_data'].str.replace('$', '')
```